# Populate next row event in current row based on the event in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| BrkPressState | VehSpdGS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 0 | 12 |
| 0 | 13 |
| 0 | 11 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 0 | 15 |
| 0 | 14 |
| 0 | 15 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 13 |
| 0 | 14 |

For the above table i am trying to populate the next row value in previous last event, Like the below table

I tried with Shift - 1 but its populating only for the current row , Sample code which i tried.

```
d['result']=d.loc[d['BrkPressState'] != d['BrkPressState'].shift(-1), 'VehSpdGS']
```

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: What's the expected output? What's the condition, `BrkPressState`? Please state

Comment: Expected output I attached as screen shot , need to populate the value of next row in previous cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `diff` to compare the previous and current row in `BrkPressState` column in order to identify boundaries, then `mask` and `shift` the values in `VehSpdGS` column

```
m = df['BrkPressState'].diff().ne(0)
df['Results'] = df['VehSpdGS'].mask(~m).shift(-1)
```

---

```
    BrkPressState  VehSpdGS  Results
0               1         2      NaN
1               1         3      NaN
2               1         2      NaN
3               1         4     12.0
4               0        12      NaN
5               0        13      NaN
6               0        11      3.0
7               1         3     15.0
8               0        15      NaN
9               0        14      NaN
10              0        15     12.0
11              1        12      NaN
12              1        13     14.0
13              0        14      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two masks for finding `vals` and `idxs` and set values to index for `result` column.

```
mask1 = df['BrkPressState'] != df['BrkPressState'].shift()
vals = df.loc[mask1, 'VehSpdGS'][1:].values

mask2 = df['BrkPressState'] != df['BrkPressState'].shift(-1)
idxs = df.loc[mask2, 'VehSpdGS'][:-1].index

df.loc[idxs, 'result'] = vals
print(df)
```

---

```
    BrkPressState  VehSpdGS  result
0               1         2     NaN
1               1         3     NaN
2               1         2     NaN
3               1         4    12.0
4               0        12     NaN
5               0        13     NaN
6               0        11     3.0
7               1         3    15.0
8               0        15     NaN
9               0        14     NaN
10              0        15    12.0
11              1        12     NaN
12              1        13    14.0
13              0        14     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @Imahdi, Its working fine and its ease to understand. However I also liked the Shubham's answer posted above using one mask.

Comment: Can you please say how did you added output as such? When ever I try to copy paste it displays in single line output.

Comment: just format the ouput as code @GodWin

Answer (score 1):

You can also do `shift(-1)` on `VehSpdGS` and then replace values with `NaN` if `df['BrkPressState'] != df['BrkPressState'].shift(-1)`

Code:

```py
df["result"]=df["VehSpdGS"].shift(-1).where(df['BrkPressState'] != df['BrkPressState'].shift(-1),pd.NA)
df
```

output:

|  | BrkPressState | VehSpdGS | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | NaN |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | NaN |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | NaN |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 12.0 |
| 4 | 0 | 12 | NaN |
| 5 | 0 | 13 | NaN |
| 6 | 0 | 11 | 3.0 |
| 7 | 1 | 3 | 15.0 |
| 8 | 0 | 15 | NaN |
| 9 | 0 | 14 | NaN |
| 10 | 0 | 15 | 12.0 |
| 11 | 1 | 12 | NaN |
| 12 | 1 | 13 | 14.0 |
| 13 | 0 | 14 | NaN |